# Wrapping if-else statement in content_tag for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I wrap if-else statement in a content_tag?

```
def entry_template
    content_tag(:div, :class => "item_title") do
      "<h3>


       if x == 'garage'
         #{entry.garage.name}
       else
         'Not garage'
       end


       </h3>"
    end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def entry_template
    content_tag(:div, :class => "item_title") do
      "<h3>" +
       if x == 'garage'
         entry.garage.name
       else
         'Not garage'
       end +
       "</h3>"
    end
end
```

or, in my eyes somewhat nicer, since it doesn't switch styles all the time,

```
def entry_template
    content_tag(:div, :class => "item_title") do
      content_tag(:h3) do
        if x == 'garage'
          entry.garage.name
        else
          'Not garage'
        end
      end
    end
end
```